# Unable to add Expires or Cache-Control response headers for JavaScript files via ExpiresFilter

Tags: tomcat

I have a website running on Tomcat 8.0.36 on Windows. I followed this link

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html

to add Expires and Cache-Control response headers. Here is what I did:

```
<filter>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType image</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
 </init-param>
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
 </init-param>
</filter>
...
<filter-mapping>
 <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

After adding the above in web.xml, I am able to see Expires and Cache-Control response headers for css files. However, I am not able to see such response headers for Javascript files.

Anything I did is wrong or missing?

Comment: I have the same problem using Tomcat 9. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

After my tests, it seems that the correct init code for javascript should be (**x-javascript**):

```
 <init-param>
    <param-name>ExpiresByType application/x-javascript</param-name>
    <param-value>access plus 10 minutes</param-value>
 </init-param>
```